# Doing https requests through a SOCKS5 proxy (tor) with curl

Tags: curl, proxy

I have TOR setup on my system (debian) that has been tested and works well. What I am trying to do is proxy HTTPS requests through this setup.

just https works:
`curl https://www.reg.ru/whois/?dname=google.com`

Tor + http work
`curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 http://stackoverflow.com/`

**but tor with https does not work:**

`curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en`

I get an error `curl: (6) Failed to resolve "www.torproject.org" for SOCKS5 connect.`

How can I solve this?

Comment: running into same issue...I'm thinking its likely a firewall/config problem but have yet to resolve it

Comment: I have the temporary solution. I had to download just one special site, so I just added line "ip site" to hosts and after that I could download it.

Comment: same issue here. from one host (in the UK) it works ok, while from another (in France) it fails

Comment: Check this for further (up to date) options: https://blog.emacsos.com/use-socks5-proxy-in-curl.html

Comment: Related: [Using CURL with TOR as a Proxy on CentOs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39257293/427158)

Answer (score 56):

I had a similar problem, and using the option `--socks5-hostname` instead of `--socks5` to specify the proxy for curl solved the issue.

Comment: I met "curl: (7) Unable to receive initial SOCKS5 response", and don't know why.

Comment: thanks but how could you find this solution, that is great

Comment: I'm glad. Probably on some obscure mailing list after googling it.

Comment: so many years later and this is still the answer ... strange ... upvote :)